# apply function for every ith row and use columns as arguments

Tags: r, apply

I am sorry if this question has been asked before, but could not find a solution to my problem. Which `apply`-like function fits the below case?

I have an `R` function which has 3 arguments `(x, y, z)`. What it does is basically to call an `PostgreSQL` function which quires `x, y, z` and retrieve a dataframe consisting of corresponding values `a, b, c`, something like this;

```
myfunc <- function(x, y, z){
  get.df <- fn$sqldf("SELECT * FROM retrieve_meta_data('$x', '$y', '$z')")
# get.df is a dataframe consisting of x number of rows and columns a, b, c
# some dataframe manipulation... 
  return(get.df)
}
```

What I am looking for is to call this function by using a dataframe `(call.df)` with x number of rows and columns `x, y, z`. So `apply` the function for each ith row and using the columns as arguments.

I have looked through a range of `apply`-like functions but I have failed so far. It's probably way easy.

I imagine something like `apply(call.df, c(1,2), myfunc)` but this gives the error;

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

I hope am clear enough without supplying any dummy data. Any pointers would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If x, y, and z are the first three columns of df, then this should work:

```
apply(df,1,function(params)myfunc(params[1],params[2], params[3]))
```

`apply(df,1,FUN)` takes the first argument, `df`, and passes it to FUN row-wise (because the second argument is 1). So in `function(params)`, params is a row of `df`. Hence, `params[1]` is the first column of that row, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This version will work if your arguments are of different types, though in this case it looks like they are all character or can be treated as such so `apply` works fine.

```
sapply(
  split(df, 1:nrow(df)),
  function(x) do.call(myfunc, x)
)
```

Comment: Ah, yes, of course! Nice with different solutions. Cheers y'all!

Answer (score 2):

It's helpful if you supply sample data so you get an answer that matches your situation, but it sounds like you're looking for `mapply`, e.g.,

```
do.call(mapply, c(myfunc, call.df[c(x.col, y.col, z.col)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just apply over `1` for your margin; then the row is passed to your function as a vector and you should be able to deal with it. For example:

```
> apply(iris, 1, function(v) paste(v["Species"], v["Sepal.Width"]))
[1] "setosa 3.5"     "setosa 3.0"     "setosa 3.2"     "setosa 3.1"
...
```